# Capture a video locally in Adobe Air app

Tags: video, air, video-capture

Is it possible to capture a video locally with [StageVideo](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageVideo.html) in Adobe Air 4 or do I need an Red5 or Adobe Media server for it?
(I basically would like to record a short 10 second long clip with audio - kinda like the [Vine app](http://vine.co))